# Create new tab for each google search by selenium in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to do google search based on some data in column A in Sheet1 .. and I need each cell content to be opened in new tab and do the search for that cell
example: A1 has the word 'flower' so I expect to create a tab and navigate to google the do a search for that 'flower' then the next cell and so on
and each search to be in a new tab
Here's my try

```
Sub Test()
Dim bot         As New ChromeDriver
Dim Keys        As New Keys

bot.Get "https://www.google.com"
'search for items in column A

bot.ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", "https://www.google.com"
bot.SwitchToNextWindow
End Sub
```

I also tried that part

```
bot.FindElementById("gsr").SendKeys Range("A1").Value
bot.SendKeys bot.Keys.Enter
bot.SwitchToNextWindow
```

But I couldn't create a new tab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following. You need to target the search box for text input.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim bot As ChromeDriver, keys As New keys, arr(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Set bot = New ChromeDriver
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<==Adjust to your sheet
    arr = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:A3")) '<== Adjust to your range

    With bot
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get "https://google.com/"
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If Not IsEmpty(arr(i)) Then
                If i > 1 Then
                    .ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", "https://google.com/"
                    .SwitchToNextWindow
                End If
                .FindElementByCss("[title=Search]").SendKeys arr(i)
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Stop '<==Delete me later
End Sub
```

---

Using a timed loop to find the element:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim bot As ChromeDriver, keys As New keys, arr(), ws As Worksheet, i As Long
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Dim ele As Object, t As Date
    Set bot = New ChromeDriver
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")   '<==Adjust to your sheet
    arr = Application.Transpose(ws.Range("A1:A3")) '<== Adjust to your range

    With bot
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get "https://google.com/"
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If Not IsEmpty(arr(i)) Then
                If i > 1 Then
                    .ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", "https://google.com/"
                    .SwitchToNextWindow
                End If
                t = Timer
                Do
                    DoEvents
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set ele = .FindElementByCss("[title=Search]")
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
                Loop While ele Is Nothing

                If Not ele Is Nothing Then
                    ele.SendKeys arr(i)
                Else
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Stop                                         '<==Delete me later
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. QHarr. I have encountered an error at this line `.FindElementByCss("[title=Search]").SendKeys arr(i)` .. Element not found for CSS

Comment: Works for me but perhaps you need a loop for it to be present. I will write something now and add in.

Comment: Can you also confirm that in your local version which opens that [title=Search] works. Select the search box and right click inspect element then check it has an attribute title with value Search. It is possible your local version may have something different. In that is the case, please share the HTML for that element.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have inspected the input and found that search is used in Arabic `Set ele = .FindElementByCss("[title=بحث]")` and this worked .. Now it is all fine as for creating new tabs and sending the keywords .. but it doesn't click on the search button so as to perform the search

Comment: I used this line `bot.SendKeys bot.keys.Enter` after the sendkeys and it worked well. Thank you very much. You're a legend

Comment: No worries. Sorry I didn't know if you just wanted to input the value or initiate the search which is why I simply left as input.